# How can I parse output from exec.Command while still logging in realtime to os.Stdout?

Tags: go

In a small Go app I'm shelling out to run a command using the os/exec package. Currently I'm passing through the log output by setting:

```
cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
err := cmd.Run()
```

What I'd like to do now is grab the output of the log (specifically the 2nd last line) and store that in a variable. I thought this would be as easy as changing `err := cmd.Run()` to `cmdOutput, err := cmd.Output()` and parsing the log string for the value I'm looking for - however this triggers an error saying `exec: Stdout already set`.

I could remove the setting of `cmd.Stdout`, but I would still like the rest of the log output to be passed through the  current process the same way it is now.

I have control over the program that I am shelling out to as well, so if there's a better way to send a JSON snippet from a child command/process to the parent Go app other than writing a file to disk, that would work too.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - I'm a bit of a golang scrub...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`io.MultiWriter`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#MultiWriter) together with [`bytes.Buffer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer) for that:

```
var errBuf, outBuf bytes.Buffer
cmd.Stderr = io.MultiWriter(os.Stderr, &errBuf)
cmd.Stdout = io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, &outBuf)
err := cmd.Run()
```

This will still log to `os.Stdout` and `os.Stderr`, but you can use `errBuf.Bytes()` to get the error output and `outBuf.Bytes()` to get the normal output. `outBuf.Bytes()` will give you a byte slice equivalent to the one returned by `cmd.Output()`.